# Javascript Help - Add Link To Image That Pops Up On Body Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Im trying to make the image link to an external source like www.google.com but I can't seem to figure it out.

The page is www.warrenmews.com/index2.html
The javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.fn.colorbox({href:"/assets/img/popup.jpg", open:true});


    }, 20);
});  
</script>
```

Im using the colorbox jQuery lightbox to do this. I just cant figure out how I can make the image clickable to an outside link.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `href`, use `html` like so:

```
$.fn.colorbox({
  html:"<a href='http://outside_link.com/'><img src='/assets/img/popup.jpg'></a>",
  open:true,
});
```

Of course, replace the URL with the correct one. You can of course set `target='_blank'` on the anchor tag to open in a new tab/window.

Comment: Thanks Cymen - I tried it, but didnt seem to work.. go to www.warrenmews.com/index3.html and it doesn't even load now.. the 20 at the end was set for it to open as soon as someone loads the page. So the timeout.

Comment: @user3666338 Try increasing that 20 milliseconds in the wait to maybe 1000 (a second). Just to debug. I'm not sure what is going on. If I just paste this into a console open on your page: `function openColorbox() {
  $.fn.colorbox({html:"<a href='http://outside_link.com/'><img src='/assets/img/popup.jpg'></a>", open:true});

 }` and then run `openColorbox()` in console it works correctly.